# Accidentally pulled out the usb while writing to disk

Tags: usb, partitioning

So i have this USB drive. I was copying something to it. While I tried to remove it safely, it showed still writing to disk. I pulled it out by mistake and now it's not working. If I plug it on windows, format disk keeps popping up again and again and won't let me do anything. On Linux I'm able to attach the USB but nothing shows up. The device gets connected to /dev/sdb but no matter what I do, I get the error of Input/Output. I have spent hours to try to fix this. Have read many many forums suggesting fixes like fdisk -l or dd command but everything returns with the same Input/Output error. Gparted also gives the same error.[Screenshot is attached of gparted showing some basic information about the drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3egHw.png).

Please help.

Comment: I have done this before and it destroyed my flash drive.

Comment: I have two ADATA flash drives with the same issue. It's sad that I'm having such a hard time fixing it.

Comment: Have you tried using testdisk and photorec on it?

Comment: Yes i did tried testdisk. The only option that seemed to be doing something was "rebuild bs" but it rakes for ever to complete. Everything else is giving input output error.